# CSS/PHP Validation error when using UTF-8?

Tags: php, css

I am trying to validate my CSS/PHP file but getting this error: **Unknown error org.w3c.www.http.HttpInvalidValueException: Invalid content type.**

I am using my PHP Headers like this:`<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");?>` 
But CSS Validator throws an error. 
So I changed my code to:`<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: utf-8");?>` and again it trows an error:(

But if I change my code to: `<?php header("Content-type:text/css;");?>` ***it passes validation...***

I am not sure why is this happening (is it maybe because I have defined UTF-8 charset inside my HTML page?).
*So can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?*
If what is worth my HTML looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>My Site Title</title> 
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.mypage.com/foldername/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.mypage.com/foldername/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/functions/dynamic_css.php">
</head>
```

Comment: `charset=`, not `charset:`

Comment: Damn always little thing's... Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"
```

should be defined as:

```
"Content-type: text/css; charset= UTF-8"
```